# Difference between -g and -gfull in Clang

Tags: c++, c, clang

The title says it all. I looked everywhere on Clang's docs, but the option `-gfull` hasn't got any description. 
The documentation also lacks information about all of the various debug levels (like `-g2`), and it would be cool if someone could explain that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, options `-g0`, `-g1`, `-g2`, `-g3` and `-gfull` in Clang are equivalent to GCC's. I could not find their documentation in Clang, but I found some info about their use in GCC (and they *should* behave the same in Clang, but I'm not 100% sure):

- `-gfull` is used on Darwin/macOS. Using `-gfull` is equivalent to `-g -fno-eliminate-unused-debug-symbols`. Sources: [link1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) [link2](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DriverInternals.html).
- `-g0` to `-g3` are debug levels. They specify how much debugging information to include (note that `-g0` means no debugging info at all). See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) for a more detailed explanation (you find them under the paragraph `-glevel`).

EDIT:

All these command line options are listed in the Clang manual as GCC-compatible options ([source](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)). Therefore, the behavior described in the GCC manual should be the same in Clang.

P.S.: I've already said that in the original answer, but now I added a link to the Clang manual as source.

Comment: Yeah, I too read GCC's manual and found the various `-glevel`s, but I thought that on Clang they could behave a bit differently ('cause they are just listed ad _compatible_), so I just asked for more precise information. And thank you for the `-gfull` part of the answer, exactly what I was looking for.